# How to check for value equality?

Tags: java

I'm a Java-beginner, so please bear with this one.

I have a class:

```
class Point {
  public int x;
  public int y;

  public Point (int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

I create two instances:

```
Point a = new Point(1, 1);
Point b = new Point(1, 1);
```

I want to check if these two points are at the same place. The obvious way, `if (a == b) { ... }`, does not work since this seems to be an "are the *objects* equal?" kind of test, which is not what I want.

I can do `if ( (a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y) ) { ... }`, but that solution does not feel good.

How can I take two Point-objects and test them for equality, coordinate wise, in an elegant way?

Comment: A good place to start is by reading the code which is already there in the JDK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard protocol is to implement the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
class Point {
  ...
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Point)) return false;
    Point rhs = (Point)obj;
    return x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y;
}
```

Then you can use `a.equals(b)`.

Note that once you've done this, you also need to implement the [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method.

For classes like yours, I often use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)'s [`EqualsBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html):

```
class Point {
  ...

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `null` check when using `instanceof`, if its argument is `null` it just returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks, this works as a charm.

I'm just wondering if I have to do something fancy in the overridden `hashCode()`, or if something like this will do: `return (this.x * 1000) + (this.y * -1000)`. Both x and y will be within 0-500 and never negative.

Comment: @bos then a simple `return this.x * 1000 + this.y;` will result in a unique hash. @aix I always have to remind myself of this fact when I write another `equals` :-)

Comment: @bos: That'll work just fine. The main requirement is that whenever `equals()` returns `true` for two objects, the objects' hash codes must be the same. Your function satisfies this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.  If you're using Eclipse, you can have Eclipse do this for you by going to `Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()..`.  After you override these methods, you can call:

```
if(a.equals(b)) { ... }
```